# Ansible : Git module clone of repository while re-run is throwing exception

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible-playbook to setup server, which is cloning the repo from github.
While I am re-running the play-book, I am getting the exception as `msg: fatal: destination path '/webapps/........' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

```
TASK: [web | Setup the Git repo] **********************************************
failed: [192.168.1.96] => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin --branch master https://github.com/....../......git /webapps/....../...../....", "failed": true, "rc": 128}
stderr: fatal: destination path '/webapps/..../..../....' already exists and is not an empty directory.

msg: fatal: destination path '/webapps/..../..../....' already exists and is not an empty directory.

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

PLAYBOOK

```
- name: Setup the Git repo
  git: repo={{ git_repo }}
       version="{{ git_branch }}"
       dest={{ project_path }}
       accept_hostkey=yes
       force=yes
  when: setup_git_repo is defined and setup_git_repo
  tags: git

- name: Delete all .pyc files
  command: find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
  args:
    chdir: "{{ project_path }}"
  tags: git
```

How do I skip this step (or) over-write the files, if files are already cloned and exists in server.?.

Comment: Have you even managed to clone that directory with ansible before? The problem is that the first time you clone a git repository the destination directory needs to be empty or it won't work. That is how git clone works (it's not a problem with ansible git module). That message is generated from `git clone` command.

Comment: @StrahinjaKustudic I think he knows, and we know it as well. The point is that the ansible modules does not understand that the repo was already there and tries to clone it again.

Comment: I just tried to clone one repo in an empty directory, then I ran the playbook again and it worked without any issues. git task just reports OK. So if you had this issue, it might have been a bug and it doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 2):

I am still having the issue and figured out the following (hacky) workaround:

```html
- name: Setup the Git repo
  git: repo={{ git_repo }}
       version="{{ git_branch }}"
       dest={{ project_path }}
       accept_hostkey=yes
       force=yes
  when: setup_git_repo is defined and setup_git_repo
  tags: git
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: clone_command_res
  
- name: Only allow the expected failure
  assert:
    that: "not clone_command_res['failed'] or 'already exists and is not an empty directory' in clone_command_res['msg'].lower()"
```

In the later, it is possible that the error message can vary, depending upon your previous status (eg my error message is `Local modifications exist in repository`) or worse, git and/or ansible versions. In any case, just include the expected error messages (kind of like a try/catch).

Although it would be much nicer if there was an option for this case in ansible git module, this should do it for now.

Answer (score 1):

Why do not check if the directory exists, and if yes, do not clone it (but maybe pull it ?)

Comment: because the directory existing does not mean that it contains the git repo.  One would think the git module would know to recognize that the folder contains the requested git repo and just move on.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue.
You can easily resolve this by adding the repo name to the destination, because some other files and directories are in the destination.

The cause for your issue comes from:

> dest:
> The path of where the repository should be checked out. This is equivalent to git clone [repo_url] [directory]. The repository named in repo is not appended to this path and the destination directory must be empty. This parameter is required, unless clone is set to false.
> Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/git_module.html#parameter-dest

Have a look at the later examples here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/git_module.html#examples like this one:

```yaml
- name: Checkout a github repo and use refspec to fetch all pull requests
  ansible.builtin.git:
    repo: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples.git
    dest: /src/ansible-examples
```

In your particular case, if the repository name should be reused and ends with .git, you can also do:

```yaml
- name: Setup the Git repo
  git: repo={{ git_repo }}
       version="{{ git_branch }}"
       dest="{{ project_path }}/{{ git_repo | basename | split('.') | first }}"
       accept_hostkey=yes
       force=yes
```

Using https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples.git as git_repo,
 `"{{ git_repo | basename | split('.') | first }}"` would use the basename `ansible-examples.git` and split it at the `.` into a list `[ansible-examples, git]` and takes the first one, returning `ansbile-examples`

Answer (score -11):

Why don't you just remove folder before clone it?
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html

```
- shell: rm -fr /yourfolder
```

Comment: Don't think you should just tell people to remove directories.

Comment: It's a way to have a clean dir each time he needs to clone a repo.

Comment: But the aim of ansible is to be idempotent. It means you can play the script 10000 times, it won't do anything if it's already the most recent sources.
So that's not the solution.

Comment: in my case I have other files (ignored through .gitignore, and built with 'bundle install'. Rebuilding needs 5 minutes.